# Arrow function in AddEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, hide, addeventlistener, arrow-functions

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="hider" value="Click to hide">
```

**Why** this **works**:

JS:

```
function hide() {
   this.hidden=true;
};

hider.addEventListener('click',hide);
```

BUT, **why** this **doesn't work**:

```
hider.addEventListener('click', () => this.hidden=true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `this` in your arrow function doesn't point to the `<input>` element. It points to the scope wherein the arrow function was created. Read about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

**EDIT: Answer to question in comments**

In your case, if you want to use an arrow function in your event listener, just re-use the `hider` variable instead of `this`:

```
hider.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // use "hider" instead of "this"
  hider.hidden = true;
});
```

**Taking it further**

If you'd want to create an "element-agnostic" event handler, make it a higher order function that takes in the element to hide as a parameter and that returns an (here: anonymous) handler function. If this sounds cryptic to you, here's some example code:

```
const makeHideHandler = (element) => { // higher order function
  return () => {                       // event handler function
    element.hidden = true;             // action to perform
  };
};
```

With this, you can write a one liner to add the listener:

```
hider.addEventListener('click', makeHideHandler(hider));
```

If you want to know why it works, google for "closures".

However, the real strength of the higher order function approach becomes visible if you have more than one element that should hide the same (or other!) element(s). Consider the following:

Let's say, you have *multiple* buttons that, when pressed, should hide the *same* element. It's easy peas with `makeHideHandler`:

```
// grab all "button" elements
const hideButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.hide-button');
// grab the element to hide
const elemToHide = document.querySelector('.hide-me');

// make the handler, pass in the element that should be hidden
const hideHandler = makeHideHandler(elemToHide);

// add listeners to the buttons
hideButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', hideHandler);
});
```

Or to create buttons that hide themself after pressing:

```
const hideButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.hide-button');
hideButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', makeHideHandler(button)); // <-- pass in the button element
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Kind of understand it, but just starting out JS and have huge chaos in my head right now. So, how would I do it with an arrow function inside the event listener?